# Aggregating multiple mongo collections and alternatives

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have three collections which represent a category. When user wants to see the recent transactions happened in a category, we need to fetch from these collections and show. I saw some questions in stackoverflow mentioning aggregating multiple collections is not allowed. Then, is there any alternatives . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with thousands of records from both the collection, better you can go with "lookup" method in mongoDB. It is not advisable for billions of records.

Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

ex,

```
db.table1.aggregate([
// Join with user_info table
{
    $lookup:{
        from: "table2",       // other table name
        localField: "userId",   // name of table1 field
        foreignField: "userId", // name of table2 field
        as: "t1"         // alias for table1
    }
},
// Join with user_role table
{
    $lookup:{
        from: "table3", 
        localField: "userId", 
        foreignField: "userId",
        as: "alias name"
    }
}
]);
```